# Facing Null Point exception in declaring button and spinner - Android

Tags: java, android

Hi am trying to create a simple application using button and spinners. Here is my code. i am facing a nullpointexception error.
**Code**

```
package baman.lankahomes.lk.jaffnatemples;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public final Button btn_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
public final Spinner spn_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
public final Spinner spn_radius = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_radius);
public final Spinner spn_temple_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_temple_type);
public final Spinner Spn_no_temple = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_no_of_temples);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            validate_form();
            goToNextActivity();
        }
    });

}

public void goToNextActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchResult.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public int validate_form(){
    String from = spn_from.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(from == "Please Select"){
        show_error_message("Error!", "Please select the from location");
    }
    return 1;
}

private void show_error_message(String data, String title){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(data)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
  }

  }
```

**Layout XML**

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/search_from"
            android:id="@+id/txt_from"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_from"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_from"
            android:entries="@array/from_spinnerItems"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/distance_radius"
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_from"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_radius"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:entries="@array/distanceRadiusItems"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/temple_type"
            android:id="@+id/tv_temple_type"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_radius"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_temple_type"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_temple_type"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:entries="@array/templeTypeItems"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/nooftemples"
            android:id="@+id/tv_nooftemples"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_temple_type"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_no_of_temples"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nooftemples"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:entries="@array/NoOfTemplesItems"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_no_of_temples"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Error**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: baman.lankahomes.lk.jaffnatemples, PID: 6424
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{baman.lankahomes.lk.jaffnatemples/baman.lankahomes.lk.jaffnatemples.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
             at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1954)
             at baman.lankahomes.lk.jaffnatemples.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
             at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final Button btn_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
public final Spinner spn_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
public final Spinner spn_radius = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_radius);
public final Spinner spn_temple_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_temple_type);
public final Spinner Spn_no_temple = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_no_of_temples);
```

needs to be inside `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`..that is how your activity will know about your components avoiding the null pointer exception.

Comment: It's not the compiler because the code will compile fine. It is a RuntimeException

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
Button btn_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
```

under `onCreate(....)` and after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

do for others too

### Correct:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button btn_search;
public Spinner spn_from;
public Spinner spn_radius;
public Spinner spn_temple_type;
public Spinner Spn_no_temple;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btn_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
spn_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
spn_radius = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_radius);
spn_temple_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_temple_type);
Spn_no_temple = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_no_of_temples);

btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        validate_form();
        goToNextActivity();
    }
 });

}
```

Comment: Hy this what i was expecting. But still after doing this am facing Nullpoinrt exception

Comment: @SathyaBaman Check your Buttons and Spinner belong to activity_main.xml or not?

Comment: could you shared your layout xml file ?

Comment: Hy, i checked  Buttons and Spinner belong to activity_main.xml ..  What can be the issue?

Comment: Hy I added the Layout XML please check. tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
public final Button btn_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
public final Spinner spn_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
public final Spinner spn_radius = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_radius);
public final Spinner spn_temple_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_temple_type);
public final Spinner Spn_no_temple = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_no_of_temples);
```

to `onCreate()`  after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`